# 500 Internal server error even after restarting the service

Tags: server, http-error

I'm getting Internal server error even after restating the application service in the server. I have restarted the server and services twice, still no luck.

Any thought?

Note: application source code is not accessible.

Comment: Very close to down voting this question, what kind of server? What is the server serving? Windows/Linux? Any more information...

Comment: This error means something has gone wrong in the application on the server. It can be countless things and with this little information, it's impossible to answer. If you don't have the source, could it be you misconfigured something? Say the app is calling another service and this is not available (e.g. because of wrong base url, firewall, etc). You'd likely get a 500.

Comment: Its windows server, postgres db... some suggestion from internal team was "database connection is not working correctly". Should i try a db server restart?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly restarting is not answer for all questions :) .
5xx is Internal Server error.. You need to check log files of your application which will clearly give u the idea.